# Using Self Resizing inside HeightOfRow

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, swift3

In *table view controller*. I have number rows and I'm using `Auto-layout` to manage the components in `prototype-cell`.

**Requirement:** Need to hide few rows based on user input.

**Problem:** When I hide the cell then grey area appeared thus I had to use `Height of Row` method to return 0 if row is hidden but for the enabled rows else I am using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` row height for each cell so that height can be calculated dynamically as per the requirement.

**Goal:** Need to *hide* few rows and show few rows
as per the dynamic requirement. I need to use Self Resizing feature so that cell height is automatically calculated as per its components.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Explain more your question.

Comment: In table view controller. I have number rows.They are being printed with the help of self resizing enabled (Auto Layout) 
Requirement: Need to hide few rows based on user input
Problem: When i hide  then grey area appeared thus i had to use Height of Row method to return 0 if row is hidden but for the enabled rows I want to use self resizing instead of giving my own height.
Thus i need to use height of row in some rows and self resizing feature in some others (iOS Swift 3)

Comment: Can you show me your UI ScreenShot so that i give answer more precisely. and add your code of work also, so that I can estimate the mistake.

Comment: PLease show some screenshots. and constraints of your cell as well.

Answer (score 0):

just return 0 in your tableview's delegate method didSelectRow whenever you want to hide this cell